# How do I call different parts of a list in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

This is my code:

```py
list0 = ["1 - Example", "2- Example"]
list1 = ["link1.com", "link2.com"]
list2 = ["Description1", "Description2"]
list3 = ["1.1 - Example", "1.2 - Example", "1.3 - Example", "1.4 - Example", "2.1 - Example", "2.2 - Example", "2.3 - Example"]
list4 = ["link3.com", "link4.com", "link5.com", "link6.com", "link7.com", "link8.com", "link9.com"]
list5 = ["Description3", "Description4", "Description5", "Description6", "Description7", "Description8", "Description9"]
numbs = ["0, 3", "4, 6"]
numb = 0
for x in list1:
    print(list0[numb],",", list1[numb], ",", list2[numb])
    print(list3[numbs[numb]], list4[numbs[numb]], list5[numbs[numb]])
    numb += 1
```

This is the output I desire:

```
1 - Example, link1.com, Description1
1.1 - Example, link3.com, Description3
1.2 - Example, link4.com, Description4
1.3 - Example, link5.com, Description5
1.4 - Example, link6.com, Description6
2 - Example, link2.com, Description2
2.1 - Example, link7.com, Description7
2.2 - Example, link8.com, Description8
2.3 - Example, link9.com, Description9
```

However, I run into this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Why is `numbs` a list of strings, rather than a list of lists of ints?

Comment: This isn't a question about Python. This is a question of how to structure your data. Take a step back and ask yourself what pattern you *want* out of this data. "This is what it looks like" is a good start, but how did *you* come up with that output? Can you put that process into words? If you can, then try putting those words into code.

Comment: Because I want it to get the 1st through 4th items of the list and 5th through 7th items of the list, not specific ones

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a string like `"0, 3"` as a subscript in a list. You should put tuples or lists in `numbs`.

You also need to loop over the range of indexes specified by those tuples. A single `print()` call won't automatically loop and print multiple lines.

You can use `zip()` to loop over multiple lists together, and slices to loop over ranges of lists.

```
list0 = ["1 - Example", "2- Example"]
list1 = ["link1.com", "link2.com"]
list2 = ["Description1", "Description2"]
list3 = ["1.1 - Example", "1.2 - Example", "1.3 - Example", "1.4 - Example", "2.1 - Example", "2.2 - Example", "2.3 - Example"]
list4 = ["link3.com", "link4.com", "link5.com", "link6.com", "link7.com", "link8.com", "link9.com"]
list5 = ["Description3", "Description4", "Description5", "Description6", "Description7", "Description8", "Description9"]
numbs = [(0, 3), (4, 6)]

for name, url, description, (start, end) in zip(list0, list1, list2, numbs):
    print(f"{name}, {url}, {description}")
    for subname, suburl, subdesc in zip(list3[start:end+1], list4[start:end+1], list5[start:end+1]):
        print(f"{subname}, {suburl}, {subdesc}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)s. You just need to add one to the stop numbers.

You'll also need to loop over the results. You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to loop in parallel.

```
slices = [slice(0, 4), slice(4, 7)]
for x0, x1, x2, s in zip(list0, list1, list2, slices):
    print(x0, x1, x2, sep=', ')
    for x3, x4, x5 in zip(list3[s], list4[s], list5[s]):
        print(x3, x4, x5, sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
1 - Example, link1.com, Description1
1.1 - Example, link3.com, Description3
1.2 - Example, link4.com, Description4
1.3 - Example, link5.com, Description5
1.4 - Example, link6.com, Description6
2- Example, link2.com, Description2
2.1 - Example, link7.com, Description7
2.2 - Example, link8.com, Description8
2.3 - Example, link9.com, Description9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused concept of list between string.

```
numbs = ["0, 3", "4, 6"]
```

variable numbs is list having data "0, 3", "4, 6" also "0, 3" and  "4, 6" is just data it self.

**not contain 0,3 in "0, 3", 4,6 in "4, 6"**

If you want make your numbs list having 0, 3, 4, 6 elements in divided two section(list,tuple,dictionary) you should set your variable numbs with double list, tuple, dictionary like code below

```
numbs = [(0,3),(4,6)]
numbs = [{0,3},{4,6}]
numbs = [[0,3],[4,6]]
```

And I think you want to select different length of each list at the same time.
Like when you count 1 on your right hand and count 1 to 5 on the other hand.

So i recommend you code below.

```
 list0 = ["1 - Example", "2- Example"]
 list1 = ["link1.com", "link2.com"]
 list2 = ["Description1", "Description2"]
 list3 = ["1.1 - Example", "1.2 - Example", "1.3 - Example", "1.4 - Example", "2.1 - Example", "2.2 - Example", "2.3 - Example"]
 list4 = ["link3.com", "link4.com", "link5.com", "link6.com", "link7.com", "link8.com", "link9.com"]
 list5 = ["Description3", "Description4", "Description5", "Description6", "Description7", "Description8", "Description9"]
    
 for i in range(2):
   print(list0[i], list1[i], list2[i])
   if i == 0: 
     for i in range(4): 
       print(list3[i], list4[i], list5[i])
    elif i == 1:
      for i in range(4,7):
        print(list3[i], list4[i], list5[i])
```